# Alert show when extension of FileUpLoads are not allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a asp FileUpload control in my aspx page.

And the code behind to check file's extension and then insert them into database:

```
 private string Write(HttpPostedFile file, string table)
    {
        string fileNameMain = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

        // check for the valid file extension
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileNameMain).ToLower();
        if (fileExtension.Equals(".pdf") || fileExtension.Equals(".doc"))
        {
            ...insert fileupload into database
        }
        else
        {
            LabelError.Text = "Extension of files are not allowed.";
            return null;
        }
    }
```

With the code above, it checks the extension and then show the message `"Extension of files are not allowed."` in a `LabelError` if the fileupload is not allowed.

Now, I'm required to do the "`check-extension`" in the other way: at the moment the client click and choose FileUpload, an `alert` show "`Extension of files are not allowed.`".

I need a way to make an alert show at the momment the FileUpload choosed in browser. Help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi but if you want an Alert (JavaScript) but first you need an postback action to execute code vb and the alert for example you could use a button to execute this method. You can show alert with this code

```
string script = "alert('Extension of files are not allowed');";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", script , true);
```